# Match all regex patterns until a delimiting pattern is reached

Tags: regex, pcre

I have the following regex expression:

```
\w{6,}(?=(\s|\n)*hello there)
```

I am trying to match all patterns until the string "hello there" is reached.

```
ASD abc1234 
fegds abc12345 
xyz456 GD (jdkjf)
xyz1234 GD (jdkjf)
(jsdfk) def123 kjfg abc493 

hello there

kjfg feg4493
```

It only seems to match "abc493" whereas it should really match all 6 patterns:
"abc1234",
"abc12345",
"xyz456",
"xyz1234",
"def123", and 
"abc493"

How do I modify the above regex expression to get the correct result?

Comment: What exactly should be matching in the 7 lines of sample text above?  This is not clear to me?

Comment: Check out regex global and multi-line flags

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I am trying to match, for example, "abc1234" "abc12345" "xyz456" "xyz1234" "def123" "abc493" in the sample text via w{6,}

Comment: yes, the /gm flag it on, but does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PCRE you could use backtracking verbs instead of lookaheads, which in this scenario performs better:

```
(?s)hello there.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\w{6,}
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/OMz4Oy/1)

Comment: If we tell in terms of performance then ``.*(SKIP)`` is a poor solution. Espeсially when a tail part (after "hello there") is quite large. Use (*COMMIT) instead: ``(?s)hello there(*COMMIT)(*F)|\w{6,}``

Comment: The size of input string doesn't affect `.*` performance.  `(*COMMIT)(*F)` is a good choice to drop `.*` and prevent a few more steps from being taken, but that doesn't surpass current solution by any means.

Comment: ``but that doesn't surpass current solution by any means``. Unfortunately its not always true until you eliminate "global" option from your solution. If PCRE JIT used (I recommend use it) then a 20MB tail after "hello there" brings a 10000 times slower match with ".*(*SKIP)" compared with "(*COMMIT)".

Comment: And if even you remove "global" then match will remian same slow if subject string does not contain "hello there"

Comment: @Michail *brings a 10000 times slower match*, why it should take slower?

Comment: I guess JIT not quite optimize this pattern as pure PCRE do. I will ask Zoltan (PCRE JIT author) about that...

Comment: @Michail or on second thought, it would never happen. `.*` only happens when `hello world` is matched and since `s` flag is set, it consumes the rest of input string immediately. It doesn't take time. So it is not slower unless you tell us *why* or give us a code to reproduce.

Comment: My mistake in phrase "if subject string does not contain 'hello there'". I mean "if subject string does not contain matches before 'hello there'". When PCRE start ".*" then it slows as more as large a tail is.

Comment: Yet it doesn't change anything. Both verbs from your regex and mine and that greedy dot  only happen when there is a `hello world`. So if there is no matches before `hello world` they just behaved the same by trying to match `\w{6,}`.

Comment: execute ``pcre2test -TM 3000 input.txt output.txt`` with input.txt containing ``/(?s)hello there.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\w{6,}/memory,jit\r\n
hello there <and then 5MB of any symbols>``. Then change ".*(*SKIP)" to "(*COMMIT)". Then compare timings.

Comment: I was able to reproduce but I could say this doesn't happen on PHP versions that use PCRE 8.* and JIT is enabled. So I guess this is PCRE 10.* specific. I do not have original `pcretest` but that may confirm it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193929/discussion-between-michail-and-revo).

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the version of your current pattern which you intended:

```
\w{6,}(?=[\s\S]*\bhello there\b)
```

The issue here is that you want to match across lines.  Perhaps `.*` by itself would not do that with your current tool.

If your regex flavor happens to support DOT ALL mode, then you may use the following pattern:

```
\w{6,}(?=.*\bhello there\b)
```

Here is a demo for the second `.*` version, which uses DOT ALL mode, showing that your six expected matches turn up.

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch all the 6-characters strings that precedes `hello there`, the correct regex is:

```
\w{6,}(?=[\s\S]*hello there)
```

Where `[\s\S]` means any character that is a space or not (practically everything, equivalent to `(?s).*`, if you want to use the [single line mode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)).

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/BGdj0H/1) for a demo.

P.S. If you want `hello there` to be a full-line delimiter, replace it with `(?m)^hello there$`